# Typing a returned observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic2, return-type

Whenever I try to transpile the following code, I receive the error:

```
TypeScript error: /Users/development/Desktop/Source/MyApp/MyApp/app/providers/register-service/register-service.ts(30,12): Error TS2322: Type 'Observable<{}>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<string>'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Yet I cannot see anything (obviously) wrong with my code:

```
getRegisteredName(): Observable<string> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
        let registeredName: string = localStorage.getItem('RegisteredName');

        if (registeredName) {
            observer.next(registeredName);

            observer.complete();
        }
        else {
            observer.error(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Why is the TypeScript transpiler rejecting this function?

Comment: Have you tried `return new Observable<string>(..)`?

Comment: This was it - thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified the type of Observable you are going to return:

```
Observable<string>
```

but the TS doesn't really know at this point what are you really returning. You have to tell it to TS compiler by doing:

```
return new Observable<string>
```

Comment: Legend - thank you! It's not obvious until you're told, then you realise just how obvious it is :)

Comment: Great! If works fine than please accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I thought I had but appears I didn't! Have done now :)